# Discussions in the meta allowed or not?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm confused. I'm new to the meta, and I get things are different here, but I'm not exactly sure how different they are. [Over here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted?rq=1) the question was answered by the person asking within the room that's normally reserved for explaining the question. And then in a field that's normally for giving the answer is a post that would normally be a comment. and then as comments on that is a discussion / banter like you'd see it in a forum. Why exactly isn't the meta aspect of rpg.stackexchange a forum?

Would it be useful (and possible) to create the option to "post" instead of "ask" in the context of the meta? Or is that already the case and it's just called "ask question" because of the way the software works? [Here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/where-should-i-ask-discussion-questions) it was said the meta not a like forum... Can someone make sense of the first link and what happened there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can and often do have discussions on Meta, but they're about the site, such as policy discussions. You can check out the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag to see what sort of discussions happen on Meta.

There are just fewer formal operating procedure rules back here. Questions don't have to be questions and answers don't have to be stand-alone, and comments are used extensively.

The Q&A format is still useful back here though – just like your Q and this A. The software is built for Q&A, and it would be more bother than help to have a custom forum for Meta, and questions like yours wouldn't benefit from a change in software anyway.

Comment: Almost figured. Thanks for clarifying! :-)